Encryption error Kerberos SPNEGO SSO Setup
Despite configurations, I keep encountering the error: "Unable to decrypt AES-256" while trying to access the application.
I've developed an internal Java 17 spring-boot application with SSO validation using Kerberos and SPNEGO. I have an SSO and Regular login page; if the SSO validations fail, user can log in using their credentials. Our setup includes the following:
AD: Azure AD
KDC: Multiple (Local)
Application Host Server: Azure cloud
Application Server: Tomcat 10.1

I've created a unique user in AD with admin privileges and enabled AES encryption types (AES-256, AES-128, RC-HMAC) for both the user and the computer.
I’ve also generated a keytab file with the same encryptions, configured Tomcat with the appropriate credentials, and set up the krb5.ini and jass.conf.ini files.
